# Dart en- and decrypt string using public and private key

Tags: dart, openssl, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

Is there a way given a file of a public and a private key to en- and decrypt a String using dart? I'm talking about a high level interface for this because the existing libraries like cipher only enable low level access and a manual extraction of modulus and public exponent.

Comment: the key actually is the modulus and public exponent. So just use it.

Comment: But that would involve parsing the key which is not part of a high level api

Comment: That depends how you transfer the key. I know login-systems where I get a json with modulus and exponent directly.

Comment: I only have the key file. This is also for command line usage.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I wrote my own RSA implementation.
If anybody else needs something like this (high level
access to encryption and decryption methods), here
is the link:

https://github.com/Adracus/rsa

Comment: You might want to show how your library should be used in the answer itself in addition to the link. It's always good to include some code if one references a library even if you did write it yourself.

Comment: You might want to implement OAEP, because PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is not regarded secure anymore.

Comment: Thanks! Code samples would be good though.  I'm trying to figure out how to encypt with just the public key (because the dart app doesn't have the private key) and am stumped.

Comment: Currently, I'm quite busy with other projects, but if you want to encrypt with your public key only, use `KeyPair.parsePem` and input the public key as String. The KeyPair instance then only has a public key instance and the private key is null. After that, you can simply use `encrypt`, which encrypts with the public key.

Comment: @Adracus can you show how to use this in flutter? and does this still work in dart2.0